# Is commuting on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Today someone asked a question about [travel times for his proposed daily commute](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/60710/3221) for his new job. The question was not well received (though that was partly due to it being poorly written prior to being edited), and attracted this comment:

> This is not really a travel question.

Is there a minimum distance one must travel in order for it to be a "real" travel question? Or must one not make a journey regularly for a question about it to be "real"?

Where do we draw the line here?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I do think the question you linked to is off topic.  I cannot explain why I think that it's off topic; it's a feeling I got when I read it.

Comment: @GayotFow "I know it when I see it" may work for the US Supreme Court, but I have higher standards. :)

Comment: The problem isn't that the question is about commuting. The problem with that question is being awfully broad.

Comment: @Mast But if a question about commuting wasn't awfully broad, would it be on topic?

Answer (score 13):

In my opinion, commuting questions are 100% about travel and should be accepted on the site.

Of course like any other topic there will still be questions that are bad for the site for other reasons.

And we could also decide to specifically make commuting questions off-topic but this would require some kind of process such as a vote and until such time it's travel so it's on-topic.

Answer (score 8):

I guess the title which contained "new job" triggered the inner bot in us to flag it as off-topic. I also think that some of the close voters (at least me) didn't pay enough attention and tried to fix the question.

Anyway, I voted to reopen the question, I totally think it is on-topic now.

Answer (score 8):

I get the feeling that this question would have been received okay if it has been framed as a question about getting from one part of the city to another - where a good answer would be able to discuss different options.

However, even if it was framed that way, I'd still think that a commuter might have different needs compared to a traveller. A traveller would probably need to know broadly about different methods available, day passes and their cost et al. A commuter has a very specific set of needs: (presumably) needs to be at work by a fixed time each day (which can affect what methods are available) and long-term recurring costs (as opposed to day passes).

Just an example of where I think commuters vs travellers is different. Having said that, the current phrasing of the question should be broad enough to be helpful for travellers as well, hence reopening.

Answer (score 0):

From https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

> **Travel Stack Exchange** is for **road warriors** and **seasoned travelers**..

If you're not travelling to a war zone, eating something that'd be considered a pet in your home country, or defecating using a hitherto unseen contraption, you might as well be asking a bikie bar to quieten down while making a phone call.

Joking, I'm totally fine with such a question.

Comment: I have a pet prawn! I can't believe there are places in the world where they _eat_ prawns! ... Totally kidding.

Comment: Good thing we only eat shrimps. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xn_CPrCS8gs

Comment: That looked like a prawn to me!